# Android nested scrollview with recycler view inside it causes delayed rendering

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have created one layout in which I am using recycler with view and few other view inside nested scrollview. What I understand is if I put recycler view inside nested scrollview it takes time to render list items. When I check inside adapter it shows it calls `onBindholder` multiple times. If I remove nested scroll view it works fine. Code looks like :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <include
        --- ToolBar View ---/>
    <include
         --- Search View ---/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            --- Some views --- 

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
                    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_5"
                    android:splitMotionEvents="false"/>
            </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my adapter looks like :

```
    package sample.example.adapters;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter  {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Data> list;
    private  ItemClickListener itemClickListener;


    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    public PopularConditionAdapter(Context context , List<Data> list) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) holder;
        Data condition = list.get(position);
        if(condition != null && condition.getConditionTitle() != null) {
            viewHolder.conditionName.setText(condition.getConditionTitle());
            viewHolder.conditionNameInitial.setText(Tools.getUserInitial(condition.getConditionTitle()));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(popularConditionList !=null)
        {
            return popularConditionList.size();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
         public  View popularParentView;
        public TextView conditionNameInitial;
        public  TextView conditionName;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            conditionNameInitial = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.some_id);
            conditionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.test_id);
            popularParentView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.round_id);
            popularParentView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (itemClickListener != null) {
                itemClickListener.onItemClick(v, list.get(getPosition()));
            }
        }
    }

    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, Data condition);
    }

    public void reloadList(List<Data> dataList){
        list.clear();
        if(dataList!=null){
            Iterator<Data> iterator = dataList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()){
                List.add(iterator.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am also calling some time `notifyDataSetChanged`. Need some help to identify what wrong things I am doing.

Comment: I really dont care about point system over here. My question is really valid one. Please refere this document `https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render.html` for more clearification on question. I beleve if question is not valid or not self explanatory then people should ask more clearification on it before down vote the question. People who ask question here they look for help. Down voting question will discourage them( at list for new users).

Comment: Found the same problem if RecyclerView is inside NestedScrollView. Probably that the NestedScrollView control rendering of it's children. So all items in RecyclerView are rendered (onBindViewHolder call multiple times)

Comment: have you fixed this issue..? having the same problem

Answer (score -1):

`RecyclerView` has its own `NestedScrollView` so we need to disable that NestedScroll by using this code..

```
 mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I have already done that. But in my case it is causing delay issue while redering first time.

Comment: do you really need `ItemClickListener` for implement click listner? I mean it can be done by without Interface.

Comment: Is that ItemClickListener causes delay in rendering?